# BpmnError not work in activiti

Tags: java, activiti

I using boundaryerror in a bpmn2 diagram. boundaryerror in diagram add to a serviceTask then draw a flow from boundaryerror to a userTask.
I throw bpmnError in try_catch and this exception throw but activiti does not go to userTask that errorBoundry related to it.

diagram exist in bellow link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5o33i1v645mx23/MyProcess.jpg?dl=0

in serviceTask class :

```
    //  in ServiceTask class
    try
    {
        // some functionality .....

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new BpmnError(null, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//  in ServiceTask class
try
{
    // some functionality .....

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new BpmnError(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

Error Code in throw new BpmnError(null, e.getMessage()); can not be null, so I use bellow code

```
throw new BpmnError("ERROR_CODE", e.getMessage());
```